# Sticky Headers on UICollectionView with a Custom Flow Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I realise there are a number of questions already related to sticky headers but I couldn't find an answer that suited my specific needs.

I'm building an EPG, and so far have the following have the layout done in traditional layout format.

Ignore the styling as so far this project is still in its infancy. The actual data is pulled from a web service which is stored locally in a SQLite database. The first row are the times which are stored in an NSArray, and the first item in each row are the icons which are pulled from a different URL (from the data) and stored also in an NSArray. Each row is a section on its own, with a dynamic number of items(programmes) in each section. The frame of each cell (X, Y, width, height) is calculated based on the number of minutes the programme runs for and stored in a dictionary to be referenced when laid out.

My problem is now I can't figure out how to stick the first section (timeline) and the first item in each section (icons) so the EPL gets pushed underneath them when the user scrolls. Here is my prepare layout method:

```
- (void)prepareLayout {

    if ([self.collectionView numberOfSections] == 0) {
        return;
    }

    [self calculateFramesForAllPrograms];

    NSMutableDictionary *newLayoutInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSMutableDictionary *cellLayoutInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];

    NSLog(@"Prepare layout %lu", numOfChannels);

    for (NSInteger section = 0; section<numOfChannels+EXTRA_ROW_FOR_TIME; section++) {

        if(section==0){

            for (NSInteger item = 0; item<=HOURS_IN_A_DAY+EXTRA_ROW_FOR_TIME; item++){

                if(item==0){

                    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];
                    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *itemAttributes =
                    [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
                    itemAttributes.frame = [self frameForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    cellLayoutInfo[indexPath] = itemAttributes;

                }else {

                    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];
                    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *itemAttributes =
                    [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
                    itemAttributes.frame = [self frameForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    cellLayoutInfo[indexPath] = itemAttributes;

                }

            }

        }else{

            NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT(channel_code) AS channels FROM epg WHERE channel_code='%@", self.channelCodes[section-EXTRA_ROW_FOR_TIME]];
            NSString *completedQuery = [query stringByAppendingString:@"'"];
            //NSLog(@"string %@", completedQuery);
            db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[Utility getDatabasePath]];
            [db open];
            NSUInteger itemCount = [db intForQuery:completedQuery];

            for (NSInteger item = 0; item <itemCount+EXTRA_ROW_FOR_TIME; item++) {

                if(item==0){

                    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];
                    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *itemAttributes =
                    [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
                    itemAttributes.frame = [self frameForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    cellLayoutInfo[indexPath] = itemAttributes;

                }else {

                    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];
                    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *itemAttributes =
                    [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
                    itemAttributes.frame = [self frameForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    cellLayoutInfo[indexPath] = itemAttributes;

                }
                //NSLog(@"ITEM ATTR: %@", itemAttributes);
            }

        }

    }

    newLayoutInfo[reuseIdentifier] = cellLayoutInfo;
    self.layoutInfo = newLayoutInfo;
    //NSLog(@"Layout Info %@", self.layoutInfo);
}
```

I've been trying to follow [Brightec's tutorial](http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/uicollectionview-using-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-sticky-rows-and-columns), but have had no luck thus far working it out to suit my collection view. Any help would be much appreciated.